# How to add build ID in about dialog,

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-kepler

I'm working on RCP application. I'm using tycho to build product.

I want to add content of About Dialog, currently I'm writing it manually by editing product file under Branding tab.

Is there is any other way to add build ID for my application in about dialog.?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no direct possibility and you need to come up with some workaround. I will describe an idea, how we do it in our project.

First of all you could store your currently released version in a properties file, having something like this:

```
version=${version.major}.${version.minor}.${version.service}.${version.build}
version.major=1
version.minor=0
version.service=0
version.build=0000
```

Then we have an ANT build script, which is responsible for updating a version. It increases service version for each new build (build version is set by Hudson):

```
<target name="-setVersion" if="version.build">
    <propertyfile file="${version.file}">
        <entry key="version.build" value="${version.build}" />
        <entry key="version.service" type="int" operation="+" value="1" default="0" />
    </propertyfile>
</target>
```

Having new version you can now manipulate with xml based files, like `plugin.xml`, `feature.xml`, `.product`, `pom.xml` (for poms there is, of course, versions plugin) etc by applying xslt transformations:

```
<target name="setVersionOfProduct">
        <property name="project.name" value="com.myrcp.project" />
        <property name="product.config" value="myrcp.product" />
        <if>
            <and>
                <available file="${workspace}/${project.name}/${product.config}" />
            </and>
            <then>
                <echo message="Set version of product to ${version}" />
                <xslt in="${workspace}/${project.name}/${product.config}" out="${workspace}/${project.name}/${product.config}.tmp" style="../pdeBuild/productVersion.xsl">
                    <param name="version" expression="${version}" />
                </xslt>
                <move overwrite="true" file="${workspace}/${project.name}/${product.config}.tmp" tofile="${workspace}/${project.name}/${product.config}" />
            </then>
        </if>
    </target>
```

And finally `productVersion.xsl` file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:param name="version" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/product/@version">
        <xsl:attribute name="version"><xsl:value-of select="$version" /></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Same idea is applied to all plugins and features. After that you can run tyco to build artifact.

Another option would be to keep version in properties file, as described before and also update it by executing ANT task, but to programmatically read version property directly from this file. It would be possible if you have your own dialog, implemented in the same way as described [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/368774/).

Or if you have About dialog contents defined through [extension point](http://eclipsedriven.blogspot.com/2010/12/creating-about-dialog-for-your-eclipse.html?_sm_au_=i6HN5TQjZtHHkfNN), using `aboutText` property. You could try to read a version property from properties file in the same way it is usually done for localizations, using `%property_key` style. Though I am not sure if it is gonna work.